# Random number generator doesn't seem to save number

Tags: ruby, random

My RNG guessing game seems to generate a new number constantly, and not save the number for the current session of the game for the player to guess.

```
def initialize
  @@answer = rand(1..100).to_s
end

def answer
  @@answer
end


def guessing
  puts "What's your guess?"
  @@guess = gets.chomp.downcase
  while @@guess != answer
    wrong_answer
  end
  right_answer
end
```

Comment: I think you could use an `if` condition instead that `while` "`@guess != answer ? 'wrong_answer' : 'right_answer'`".

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @sawa, my question was how to keep the number that was generated. It kept changing with each guess. minuthouse's answer about class instance variable worked for that part. I have another problem that I need help with but I will post that in another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any problem with your code, but it could be the way are initializing the class (if you are calling guessing explicitly everytime you want to make a guess).

You need to store the initialized class in a variable:

```
guess = Guess.new
guess.guessing
guess.guessing
```

Also you don't want to use class instance variables unless necessary i.e, use `@guess`, `@answer` instead of `@@guess` and `@@answer`.

Another way

```
  def guessing
    puts "What's your guess?"
    @guess = gets.chomp.downcase
    while @guess != answer
      puts "wrong_answer"
      @guess = gets.chomp.downcase
    end
    puts "right_answer"
  end
```

Comment: wouldn't I need to create a new class for the guess in your first suggestion?

Comment: also, thank you! that worked to resolve my problem with it generating a new number each time. So the "@@"  made it a new number each time, while the "@" kept the number the same? Im going to read about class instance variable now. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you store the random number in an attr_reader, you can then reference it and compare it to the guess. If you store the guess in an attr_accessor, you can compare the guess to the stored random number and have the User continue the game by updating their guess until it matches the random number. I can include an example that you can copy and paste right into IRB. To start the game just call `PlayGame.new` and you are off and running. Enter `cheat` for the random number and `hint` for a hint.

```
class RandomNumber
  attr_reader :number

  def initialize
    @number = rand(1..100).to_s
  end

  def hint
    random_number = number.to_i

    puts case
    when random_number >= 75
      "Your number is in the range of 75 to 100"
    when random_number >= 50
      "Your number is in the range of 50 to 74."
    when random_number >= 25
      "Your number is in the range of 25 to 49"
    else random_number > 0
      "Your number is 24 or less."
    end
  end
end

class PlayGame
  attr_accessor :input
  attr_reader :number

  def initialize
    @generate_number = RandomNumber.new
    @number = @generate_number.number
    puts "What's your guess?"
    @input  = gets.chomp.downcase
    validate
  end

  def validate
    case
    when input == number
      puts "You win!"
    when input == "cheat"
      puts "The number is #{number}"
      get_guess
    when input == "hint"
      @generate_number.hint
      get_guess
    else
     get_guess
    end
  end

 def get_guess
   puts "Try again, what's your guess?"
   @input = gets.chomp.downcase
   validate
 end
end
```

Comment: intereseting, what is that called; the attr_reader? I'd like to read to documentation to try and understand it better. Also, would I be able to add the other methods to this class you created to enable to hints and cheat?

Comment: Hi Mike, here is a link to the Ruby Docs on attr_reader: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_reader and this article is helpful to read first: https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/50f0192b102455349200372d. Yea, hints and cheats could be added. I'll see if I can edit my original post with that code.

Comment: Thank you so much for that info :D @timproctor

Comment: Thank you so much Tim. I think I've got a grip on what and how attr works. I saw in your profile that you went to Turing. I start on the 1st. :D

Comment: Awesome! Congrats!